# how to make distinct type with condition in oracle

Tags: oracle, distinct, user-defined-types

```
create or replace TYPE PDV AS OBJECT 
( percentage NUMBER(4,2), 
 MEMBER FUNCTION get_percentage RETURN NUMBER
) INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;

create or replace TYPE BODY PDV AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION get_percentage RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN
    return SELF.percentage;
  END get_percentage;
END;
```

I have table Product (productID, name, description, percentage)

When I insert this in the database, it should be saved in the table Product:

```
insert into Product VALUES (1, 'Table', 'Brown table for six people.Made of oak', PDV(20.00));
```

When I insert this into the database, an error should occur:

```
insert into Product VALUES (1, 'Table', 'Brown table for six people.Made of oak', PDV(130.20));
```

I want to make distinct type with condition - percentage must be between 0 and 100. Where to put that condition?

Answer (score 0):

> percentage must be between 0 and 100. Where to put that condition?

Nowhere, I'd say. PERCENTAGE's data type, a numeric having precision 4 and scale 2 will take care about it.

As you didn't provide whole code you use, here's an example.

```
SQL> create or replace type pdv as object
  2  (productid number,
  3   name varchar2(30),
  4   description varchar2(100),
  5   percentage number(4, 2),
  6   member function get_percentage return number
  7   ) instantiable not final;
  8   /

Type created.

SQL>  create or replace type body pdv as
  2    member function get_percentage return number as
  3    begin
  4      return self.percentage;
  5    end get_percentage;
  6  end;
  7  /

Type body created.

SQL> create table product (prod pdv);

Table created.

SQL> insert into product values (pdv(1, 'Table', 'Made of oak', 20));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product values (pdv(1, 'Table', 'Made of oak', 130));
insert into product values (pdv(1, 'Table', 'Made of oak', 130))
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL> insert into product values (pdv(1, 'Table', 'Made of oak', 55.567));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, written after reading OP's comment]**

I'm not sure I understood what you mean. If it means that you want to create an *inline* CHECK constraint, well, that won't work:

```
SQL> create or replace type pdv_typ as object
  2  (
  3     producid number,
  4     name varchar2 (30),
  5     description varchar2 (100),
  6     percentage number (4, 2) constraint ch_perc check (percentage between 0 and 100),
  7     member function get_percentage
  8        return number
  9  );
 10  /
create or replace type pdv_typ as object
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
ORA-06550: line 6, column 29:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the
following:
:= ) , not null default external character
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00565: PDV_TYP must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)


SQL>
```

What you could do is to create a table whose column data type is of a previously created type, such as this:

```
SQL> create or replace type pdv_typ as object
  2  (
  3     producid number,
  4     name varchar2 (30),
  5     description varchar2 (100),
  6     percentage number (4, 2),
  7     member function get_percentage
  8        return number
  9  );
 10  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type body pdv_typ
  2  as
  3     member function get_percentage
  4        return number
  5     as
  6     begin
  7        return self.percentage;
  8     end get_percentage;
  9  end;
 10  /

Type body created.

SQL> create table pdv_tab
  2  (
  3     id    number primary key,
  4     pdv   pdv_typ constraint ch_perc check (pdv.percentage between 0 and 100)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into pdv_tab values (1, pdv_typ (1, 'Table', 'Made of oak', 20));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into pdv_tab values (2, pdv_typ (2, 'Chair', 'Made of steel', 120));
insert into pdv_tab values (2, pdv_typ (2, 'Chair', 'Made of steel', 120))
                                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL> insert into pdv_tab values (3, pdv_typ (3, 'Window', 'Made of glass', -5));
insert into pdv_tab values (3, pdv_typ (3, 'Window', 'Made of glass', -5))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_PERC) violated


SQL>
```

Personally, I really, really don't like *object* side of Oracle. For me, it is a *relational* DBMS. Object support came as if they wanted to say *hey, look, we can do that too!*. I can't remember whether I ever used that functionality, except for educational purposes. Drawbacks? Plenty. Benefits? None. Once again, from my point of view.

So, what are you, really, doing? This is not a real-life problem, is it? That suggests your comment, saying that it *has to be* done that way. Says who? If it is a client, tell him to mind his own business. If it is a professor, then do what he says, regardless.

Comment: How could I do that through setters in definition of type? That is what is requred

Comment: I think you should create a constructor in your type to check the percentage that must be between 0 and 100, Otherwise you should raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this would be a CHECK constraint on the table. That could be as simple as:

```
create table Product (
  productID number primary key
  , name varchar2(30) not null
  , description varchar2(128) not null
  , percentage number check (percentage between 0 and 100)
  );
```

Demo in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f4622/2).